File not printed using os.startfile?
i try to print a document on windows using the following code
import os
import sys    
os.startfile(r"D:/DEV/Python-Diverses/os/testb.png", "print")

But nothing happens at all - the programs runs trough but no printing.
When i just open the file with
os.startfile(r"D:/DEV/Python-Diverses/os/testb.png") 

it is opened in the image-viewer program (windows image viewer).
Any ideas why the printing is not working?

Can you print the file using right-click and selecting Print from the menu? I expect startfile() uses the same underlying mechanism.

Even if this worked, I imagine it would just display the print dialog window -- you'd still have to choose image orientation, paper size, destination printer name, etc.

When i right-click on the file and select Print - it only opens the dialog for printing.
Is there no way to directly print a document using python (to the default printer of course)?

Is the file in the location? Did you get any error?

I have same issue.I checked some documents and I found the following solution: add a time.sleep after os.startfile.
import os

import sys

import time
    
os.startfile(r"D:/DEV/Python-Diverses/os/testb.png", "print")

time.sleep(5)

It works for me.
Maybe it works for you too.
